# Cloud Firestore triggers " Your trigger must always point to a document"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

what i am trying to do is ... my document flow

**batch(collection) -> {batchName}(document) -> subjects -> {subjectName} -> attendance**

i want to trigger firestore function whenever there is an update in the attendance object

So in the documentation of the Cloud Firestore triggers, i found this line "Your trigger must always point to a document" with an example ... here is the link to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)

which gave me hope that it is possible to do that and i am failing to achieve this,

```
exports.attendenceTrigger = functions.firestore.document('batche/{batchName}/subjects/{subjectName}/attendance')
```

is it possible to do it ? if yes then what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified a path to a collection

```
'batche/{batchName}/subjects/{subjectName}/attendance'
 (col)    (doc)      (col)      (doc)       (col)
```

However, your path must point towards a document so valid paths include:

```js
// Triggers a function when a doc in subjects sub-collection is changed
'batche/{batchName}/subjects/{subjectName}'

// or

// Triggers a function when a doc in attendance sub-collection is changed
'batche/{batchName}/subjects/{subjectName}/attendance/{attendanceId}'
```

Is `attendance` a sub-collection? If yes, then use the second path above to listen trigger a function when a document in that collection is created/modified/deleted. If `attendance` is a field in a `{subjectName}` document then you should use the first line and access the `attendance` field from the snapshot `snapshot.data().attendance`.

Comment: yes,  attendance has a list of objects i.e: {attendenceId:{present: [], absent: []},attendenceId:{present: [], absent: []},attendenceId:{present: [], absent: []}}.. i put a trigger on that id but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @NaveenSharma can you share a screenshot of your Firestore document? Also the structure of db.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/MekHdnn) ... this is the image you asked and yes i am aware that attendance spelling is wrong